# Is it possible to "unmerge" two contacts?

Tags: custom-fields, import, duplicate-contacts, data-import

Two contacts in my system were accidentally merged. Is it possible to unmerge them and restore all of their respective data to the original states?

Answer (score 3):

If you have logging turned on at Administer - System Settings - Misc then the change log tab on the contact will have a "revert these changes" button if you drilldown on the "Contact Merge" entry, but (a) I'm not sure how well supported it is, and (b) if time has passed and many other changes have happened it may not do what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like the "Revert these changes" option reverts all changes, but I only want to revert a specific merge. Any suggestions?