# Is it possible with "Detailed Logging" enabled to perform a revert of a contact merge?

Tags: wordpress, extension, duplicate-contacts

I had a glitch in a script that caused some unwanted contact merges to happen programmatically:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'merge', [ 'to_remove_id' => $existingContactId, 'to_keep_id' => $contactId, 'mode' => "aggressive",]);
```

Fortunately, I had the Detailed Logging setting enabled. In theory, I could pull the change log for each unwanted merge and "revert" the merge. Does anyone know of an extension or script I can look at to accomplish this?

Comment: There is an answer here which says you should be able to do this via the Change Log - but I just gave this a whirl on dmaster and did not find any options to do so. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41703/is-it-possible-to-unmerge-two-contacts

Comment: It's there. See the button at the bottom here. https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/37?reset=1&log_conn_id=62f56b07098c77G1t&cid=206&oid=207&alteredName=Aaa%20Bbb%20[Contact%20Merged]&cid=206&alteredBy=demo@example.com&alteredById=204&section=2. To get there click on the change log tab for https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=206, then drill down on the Contact Merge entry.

Comment: hmm that link isn't working for me, even if i try just going to civicrm/report/instance/37?reset=1 without the contact IDs in it. I tried merging another couple of contacts but still not getting any results. was report=37 one you created? what is the basis of the report? or perhaps you could expand on your comment as an Answer with s'shots?